# How to create a Range from Table in schematiq

Tags: schematiq

I have a schematiq table containig data I have read from a CSV and parsed into columns. I want to create myself a data link to a range object representing each column so I can then pass those into multiple stats functions.

I've tried `=rng.Subset(B5,1,1)` on the table which I had hoped would create a range for the first column, but in the views I see I this results in a 1x1 range containing the whole table.

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return an array from a Schematiq function, there are two possible forms for that array to take. One is a "range", i.e. a data-linked object that will exist in a single cell regardless of its size, the other is an array function result, which will fill whatever range an array formula has been entered in.

The easiest way to get all the values out of a table as an array is to use `tbl.GetValues()`, which if you use it without a `column` argument just returns a rectangular array containing all the data in the table.

However, this is returned as an array function result, so in order to put it into a range you will need to use `rng.Create()` on that result. The following should work for you in this case:

```
=rng.Create(tbl.GetValues(B5))
```

Or, for a specific column:

```
=rng.Create(tbl.GetValues(B5, "ColumnName"))
```